# How do I safely drop a list of tables, when i have the table names listed in a column?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Assuming I have a database column containing table names, how do I safely delete all of the tables it lists?

The tables themselves are fairly simple - they may have indeces, but definitely don't contain other complex items (and don't have dependencies on other tables - ie, foreign keys into/out of them, etc...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something along the lines of the following should work.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TablesToDrop
(
    TableName SYSNAME
);
INSERT INTO dbo.TablesToDrop VALUES ('Table1');
INSERT INTO dbo.TablesToDrop VALUES ('Table2');
INSERT INTO dbo.TablesToDrop VALUES ('Table3');
DECLARE @Cmd NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @Cmd = '';
SELECT @Cmd = @Cmd + 'DROP TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(t.TableName) + ';'
FROM dbo.TablesToDrop T;
RAISERROR (@cmd, 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT;
--EXEC sp_executesql @Cmd;
```

Uncomment the last line to actually execute the `DROP TABLE` statements.

Answer (score 4):

if your database column contains below table names:

```
column_name 
------------ 
test_kin1 
test_kin2 
test_kin3
```

Then you can use:

```
select 'drop table '+quotename(column_name) + char(10) +'go'from table_name
```

In text mode it will generate sql to drop them. Execute the generated sql by **VERIFYING** that you indeed want to drop the tables in another query window.